# How to restore app data backups like logging in to a new device?

Tags: backup, calendar, google-drive

Basically, I have lost 60% of all my events in google calendar on both desktop and on android. I know there is a backup of the android app data from yesterday which should hopefully contain the events, how can I restore this backup from google drive?

Comment: Even if the Google calendar is included in the backup you may face two problems: 1. app backups don't have to include all the data - the developer can specify which data to backup and which not. As the google calendar data are just a local copy it may be excluded from the backup. 2. even if you manager to restore the app backup the data from the server is newer and will override the restored data.